Bird OSPF on WireGuard interfaces not working
I'm trying to announce static routes from Linux server to WG peers. But cant see any packet coming from Bird to WG peers on WG interface.
Tried interface type options: ptmp, ptp, broadcast with lo luck..
All traffic between WG peers come ok.
IPTABLES has no rules (policy ACCEPT)
Bird version 2.0.8
berd.conf
log "/var/log/bird.log" { debug, trace, info, remote, warning, error, auth, fatal, bug };

protocol device {}


protocol kernel {
        ipv4 {                  # Connect protocol to IPv4 table by channel
              import none;      # Import to table, default is import all
              export none;      # Export to protocol. default is export none
        };
}

protocol kernel {
        ipv6 { export none; };
}

protocol static STATIC {
        ipv4 { export all; };
        route 1.1.1.1/32 via 10.8.0.1;
        route 209.85.233.198/32 via 10.8.0.1;
        route 140.82.121.4/32 via 10.8.0.1;
}

protocol ospf MyOSPF {
        area 0 {
                interface "wg*" {
                        authentication none;
                        type ptmp;
                        neighbors {
                                10.8.0.3;
                        };
                        tx length 1300;
                        cost 100;              
                        hello 5;
                };
        };
}

wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/32
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = ip link set wg0 multicast on; iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
FwMark = 0xca6c
PrivateKey = wLlkhfaCVgtucw1gnE+svr4ll8ViwhgkqTCjRJfwAko=


[Peer]
PublicKey = KAMkexIcsRi4218NPg7oss3YJkn4YAqu0totQ7N0dXU=
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.3/32
Endpoint = 62.217.187.15:50130

# birdc show interfaces
BIRD 2.0.8 ready.
lo up (index=1)
        MultiAccess AdminUp LinkUp Loopback Ignored MTU=65536
        127.0.0.1/8 (Preferred, scope host)
        ::1/128 (Preferred, scope host)
ens3 up (index=2)
        MultiAccess Broadcast Multicast AdminUp LinkUp MTU=1500
        188.241.197.22/32 (Preferred, scope univ)
        fe80::5054:ff:fe73:ce7b/64 (Preferred, scope link)
wg0 up (index=9)
        PtP Multicast AdminUp LinkUp MTU=1420
        10.8.0.1/32 (Preferred, scope site)

# birdc show route
BIRD 2.0.8 ready.
Table master4:
1.1.1.1/32           unicast [STATIC 15:44:20.605] * (200)
        via 10.8.0.1 on wg0
10.8.0.1/32          unicast [MyOSPF 15:44:20.706] * I (150/0) [10.8.0.1]
        dev wg0
209.85.233.198/32    unicast [STATIC 15:44:20.605] * (200)
        via 10.8.0.1 on wg0
140.82.121.4/32      unicast [STATIC 15:44:20.605] * (200)
        via 10.8.0.1 on wg0

# birdc show ospf ne
BIRD 2.0.8 ready.
MyOSPF:
Router ID       Pri          State      DTime   Interface  Router IP

Is it normal that there is not a single neighbor, not even self?
# birdc show ospf state
BIRD 2.0.8 ready.

area 0.0.0.0

        router 10.8.0.1
                distance 0
                stubnet 10.8.0.1/32 metric 0

When i listen with tcpdump i see only packets from WG peer (Mikrotik), but not from Bird host ip (WG Server).
tcpdump -i wg0 -n -v
tcpdump: listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
15:45:31.868877 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 40884, offset 0, flags [DF], proto OSPF (89), length 64)
    10.8.0.3 > 224.0.0.5: OSPFv2, Hello, length 44
        Router-ID 10.8.0.1, Backbone Area, Authentication Type: none (0)
        Options [External]
          Hello Timer 10s, Dead Timer 40s, Mask 255.255.255.0, Priority 128
15:45:41.864248 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 41569, offset 0, flags [DF], proto OSPF (89), length 64)
    10.8.0.3 > 224.0.0.5: OSPFv2, Hello, length 44
        Router-ID 10.8.0.1, Backbone Area, Authentication Type: none (0)
        Options [External]
          Hello Timer 10s, Dead Timer 40s, Mask 255.255.255.0, Priority 128

On l2tp/IPSec interface on same host and same remote peer all works.
UPDATE:
Now all works.

Need to set /24 mask on WG interface
Allowed IP's 0.0.0.0/0 (for diagnistic) or add 224.0.0.5/32  to pass trafic
Bird interface type: ptp (and on other side Mikrotik same)

Working wg0.conf:
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
Table = off
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 11820
PrivateKey = %server private key%

[Peer]
PublicKey = %peer public key%
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 62.211.32.153:11820


From afar, I suspect the issue is that you have AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.3/32 only. As you can see, in most modes OSPF insists on sending Hello packets not to the peer directly, but to the multicast address 224.0.0.5, and it's likely that the WireGuard configuration on either end doesn't allow that.
(Although AllowedIPs is duplicated into kernel routes by wg-quick, its primary purpose is to act as an interface-internal routing table as well as a filter; only packets for matching addresses are sent to this peer, and only packets from matching addresses will be accepted from it.)
L2TP (PPP-like) interfaces have no such equivalent, they allow any traffic. So I'd change the tunnel to use AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 on both sides (and perhaps Table = none, and would remove all of the MASQUERADE rules – if you need any NAT in the middle of your network, something's gone wrong).
One alternative might be to use type nbma for the interface, defining it as one that cannot support multicast and therefore only manually specified peers are contacted via unicast (neighbors { 10.8.0.3 eligible; }).
Additionally: It might help to configure the IP address on the interface in the "point-to-point" style, i.e. 10.8.0.1/32 peer 10.8.0.3 – I seem to recall some older Bird2 versions wanted to see this and had problems doing 'PtP' OSPF mode otherwise...

You were right, AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 needed, but problem was in WG interface IP-address, it was with /32 mask, you pointed me right direction :)
